# How to create two or more buttons with two mini buttons at bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create this button combination:

[image: img]

But I can't put that two mini buttons (the red an the blue) down the main buttons, any idea how to do this?

This is what I have:

```
<button class="btn btn-info">P</button>
<button class="btn btn-info">Q</button>
<button class="btn btn-info">R</button>
<button class="btn btn-info">S</button>
<button class="btn btn-info">Z</button>
```

**EDIT**

This is what I'm working for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KDFM.png

I need two mini buttons down the skyblue buttons you see.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:left">
        <br>
        <p><strong>Número de proposiciones simples a usar: </strong><input id="inp1" type="number" min="1" max="5"></input>
        </p>
      </div>
      <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover well">
        <tr id="trL1">
          <td><b>Proposición</b></td>
          <td><b>Valor de verdad</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="trL2">
          <td id="PLF">Arma tu proposición con los botones de abajo</td>
          <td id="VoF"> ¿¿ V o F ??</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:left" id="btnsL">
          <td colspan="2" id="btnL">
            <button class="vL1 vL3i btn btn-info">(</button><button class="vL1 vL3f btn btn-info" disabled>)</button><button class="vL1 oL btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">∨</button><button class="vL1 oL btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">∧</button><button class="vL1 oL btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">⇒</button><button class="vL1 oL btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">⇔</button>
            <br>
            <button class="vL1 vL3n btn btn-info">∼</button><button class="btn btn-info">P</button><button class="btn btn-info">Q</button><button class="btn btn-info">R</button><button class="btn btn-info">S</button><button class="btn btn-info">Z</button>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="respuesta">Ver Resultado</button><button id="borrarPL">Borrar</button><button id="restartPL">Reiniciar</button>
      <p id="contC"><strong>10</strong></p> caracteres restantes<br><br><br><br>

    </div>   <!-- Fin row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="procedimiento">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover well">
          <tr style="color:rgb(100,130,130)"><td>procedimiento 1</td><td>procedimiento 2</td><td>procedimiento 3</td><td>procedimiento 4</td><td>procedimiento 5</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: sure, I'll edit and show you the rest of the code and an image of what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a very small example

```css
.buttonWrapper{
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
}

.big{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
 }

.small{
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="buttonWrapper">
  <button class="big">P</button>
  <button class="small">1</button><!--
--><button class="small">2</button>
</div>
```

I added comments between the two smaller buttons `<!-- -->` to remove the whitespace between them, so you shouldn't remove these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this of any use?

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.btn-info{  
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-size:30px;
}
.btn-miniLeft{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:50%;
  border-color:red;
}
.btn-miniRight{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  width:50%;
  border-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info">P</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniLeft">P1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniRight">P2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Q</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniLeft">Q1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniRight">Q2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info">R</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniLeft">R1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniRight">R2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info">S</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniLeft">S1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniRight">S2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Z</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniLeft">Z1</button>
      <button class="btn btn-miniRight">Z2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The same! ty so much